# html page working independently without views.py in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm developing a project in django for the 1st time. I have created a html file '**templates/app/token.html**'

```
<form action="{% url 'token' %}" method="post" name="portalForm">
    <h3>Generate a new token</h3>
    <table>
        <tr><td><b>Select Portal Name</b></td><br></tr>             

        <td><select name="portal">
            <option value=""> Please select Portal name </option>
                {% for option in portalname %}
                    <option  value={{option}} >{{option}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
        </select></td>
    
        <td><input type="submit" value="Generate token"></td>
    </table>            
</form>
```

and added a function in **views.py**

```
def token:
    context = { 'portalnames':portalList}
    return render(request,'PIM/token.html',context)
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name = 'index'),
    re_path(r'^(?P<offset>[0-9]+)',  index, name = 'index'),
    re_path(r'^q/?$', job_queue, name='job_queue'),
    re_path(r'^t/new/?$', new_test,name='new_test'),
    re_path(r'^t/(?P<test_id>[^/]+)/?$', test_detail,name='test_detail'),
    re_path(r'^t/(?P<test_id>[^/]+)/save/?$', test_save, name ='test_save'),
    re_path(r'^login/?$', login, name='login'),
    re_path(r'^account/?$', account, name='account'),
    re_path(r'^logout/?$', logout, name='logout'),
    
    url(r'authtest/', auth_test, name="authtest"),
    url(r'autht/', autht, name="autht"),
    url(r'getportal/', getportal, name="getportal"), 
    url(r'search/', search, name="search"), 
    url(r'compare/', compare, name="compare"), 
    url(r'token/', token, name="token"), 
]
```

Here there is an ambiguity in data. I'm passing 'portalnames' in views function and trying to access 'portalname' in html page. But it is working and even after tried removing the token function, the html page is not affected and it is able to produce portalnames option in html successfully.

Note: I'm using the same 'portalname' in other view and other html page. So will this html page got affected by that or how is it able to work even after removing the views function

**Important update**: I have noticed that my modifications in views function are reflecting in my html page after some hours. But if I make further modifications in the function, it is not getting reflected. Is there any logic behind that in django?

Comment: Please add your **urls.py**.  You have `/app/token.html` and `PIM/token.html`.  That, in itself is not a problem, but the question is, which template is the view pointing to?  Do you have another view function pointing to one of these templates?

Comment: sorry that was by mistake. the correct path is `templates/PIM/token.html`  which I have given correctly. so that's not an issue. my html page is not making use of the view. that is my problem. can u pls help me on this?

Comment: portalname**S** != portalname. there is no "portalname" in context passed to the template. And you removed too much code from the view when posted it here. `But it is working and even after tried removing the token function` then this is not the function you think. Some other code works. Please show all of your urls.py including import declarations.

Comment: I have included all other urls as well as u have asked. **portalname** is rendered in other views. will that anyhow affect here? for eg;- the login will also get such details. so is there any possibility for mismatch?

Comment: What is the url (not urlpattern, the actual url from browser address bar) you open? And you did not add import declarations. Please add all the code you have in urls.py and show your folder structure. Your questions about "one view affecting another" look suspicious to me, so please elaborate how you fill `portalList` variable. Show full code of `token` view.

Comment: Identified that my **html page** is updated with the modification in **views function** after some hours. The changes are not getting reflected immediately. What should I do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got a solution to my issue**. In my case, after restarting the server on doing modifications in views.py, reflected the changes in html page. It's quite annoying. But that's how it worked for me.